# CHECKING if a value exists in a table SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am making a bot where I need to store the `commandname` and `commandreply` in the database. I am using mySQL Workbench.

I want to check if the `commandname` that the user tries to make is already in the table, and if so display that. If not, then carry on (make the command).

```
connection.query("SELECT commandname FROM commands WHERE EXISTS (commandname = " + args[0] + ")"
```

(Where `args[0]` is the command name). This is what I initially thought, although I don't have much experience in SQL. I'm not sure what this would display if it exists, or if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `select 1 from commands where commandname = ?`.

Comment: Please read up on parameters, doing it with String Concatenation is exposing a SQL Injection attack: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM commands WHERE commandname = ' + args[0] + '
```

if it returns 0 then insert else update.

A better approach would be to update first and see how many rows are updated if it's 0 then insert, in which case it will run only 1 query most of the time (assuming update is more frequent than insert).